# Missing Stars in Yoshi's New Island 1-2

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, yoshis-new-island

*Yoshi's New Island*
**World 1-2**
Chomp Rock 'N' Roll

I've played this level 4 times now and I'm still missing 5 Stars.  I've found all the Red Coins and Smiley Flowers and 25 Stars.  I've explored the level quite a bit so the location of the missing 5 Stars has to be hidden.  I've found the Stars in the wood box and the Pipe which you clearbspikes off of.  Where else could they be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the hidden set I was missing.  After completing the floating balloon mini game in this level there's a hidden ? cloud above the exit door and to the left.  Jump and hold so that you flutter up to activate it.